# How to send a image base64 web services POST C#

Tags: c#, web-services, post, webforms, base64

I have a problem trying to consume an external POST web service; they ask me to send an image in base64, but when I send it, it sends me this error: Internal Server error 500. This happens before sending all the data to the web services. the image weighs 30 kb.

```
List<string> List = new List<string>();
string url = "http://xxx.cti.lat/yyy/webservices/go.php";
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
                nvc.Add("a", "pDepo");
                nvc.Add("idc", cueNatra);
                nvc.Add("idop", idop);
                nvc.Add("nrodoc", numOpe);
                nvc.Add("fechdep", "2019/06/21");
                nvc.Add("mont", moDep);
                nvc.Add("local", stble);
                nvc.Add("det", "");
                nvc.Add("tigo", tiDep);
                nvc.Add("canls", "RED");
                nvc.Add("imag64", imageDep);

                var data = wc.UploadValues(url, "POST", nvc);
var responseString = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic listMove = js.Deserialize<dynamic>(responseString);
```

The error happens in this part of my code: var data = wc.UploadValues(url, "POST", nvc);

Comment: The error doesn't indicate that you did something wrong. It means that something went wrong on their end. In a perfect world, if something is wrong with your request you'd get some sort of 400. In real life, there could be something wrong with your input, they're not handling it correctly, and they're throwing a 500. That leaves room for doubt. Do they provide a sample request? If so you could try that. If it doesn't work, it's more likely on their end. If it does work, then compare it to yours and see what you might be missing.

Comment: Admittedly, if my vision of a "perfect world" involves web requests getting 400 errors instead of 500 errors, I should probably set my sights higher.

Comment: I understand, but if I remove the image in base 64, the method works correctly.

Comment: Do you mean that it just doesn't return a 500 if you remove the image? If the purpose is to upload an image then it can't really work without the image. But unfortunately that still leaves you in the dark. Why *doesn't* it return an error if you leave out the image? Why does it return a 500? It could be anything. It could be trying to save the image, but the server's hard drive is full. Or there's a bug in their code. Or something wrong with your request that it's not handling. 500 doesn't tell you anything helpful or if it's even possible for you to fix it.

Comment: Yes, the service that I consume is external, so I do not know how they have developed it. but, if I send "imag64", " ", I do not have any error.
And it returns a list of results.

Comment: The best I can recommend is to communicate with them somehow. The problem could be your request, but if they're speaking the language correctly, they're telling you that your request is okay but their server isn't working. Imagine a method that takes two or three numbers and adds them. If you pass two numbers it works, but if you pass three numbers it throws an exception. Is the problem that you passed three numbers? Probably not. This case is more complicated, but same concept. Just because it works if you leave out some values doesn't mean the problem is on your end.

Comment: Sometimes the problem is both. Your input is wrong, and it causes their app to blow up. They should validate your input and give you a 400 so you know it's your fault. But your input is wrong in a way they didn't anticipate, although perhaps they should have. So now the input is wrong, but because they didn't anticipate it, their app fails and sends a 500, meaning that the problem is on their end, when actually it's something you could correct. That's why it's good to reach out. They might say, "Yeah, we know, it's broken," and then you know there's nothing you can do.